# How do I assign an instance of a struct to a class that contains that struct?

Tags: c#, .net, struct

I've never used structs before. I've created a simple example of what I'm trying to do below. The reason I've chosen struts is because the object will never need to exist outside the context of the class. Thanks.

**Classes**

```
public class EmailAddress
{
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class EmailMessage
{
    public EmailAddress To { get; set; }

    public EmailAddress From { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public struct Attachment
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Bas64 { get; set; }
    }
```

***Attempted Method***

```
protected void MyMethod()
{
    var myEmailMessage = new EmailMessage
    {
        To = { Email = "ToEmailAddress" }, 
        From = { Email = "FromEmailAddress" }
    };

    var myAttachment = new EmailMessage.Attachment
    {
        Name = "AttachmentName", 
        Bas64 = "Base64String"
    };

    myEmailMessage.Attachment = myAttachment;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Your email message doesn't have a property `Attachment`

Comment: Consider reading [Choosing Between Class and Struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx). I see no reason to use a `struct` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a `struct` declaration as property of your class. You should split the property and the actual `struct` definition.

Try this:

```
public _Attachment Attachment {get;set;} /* Attachment as property */

public struct _Attachment /* The definition of the struct */
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Bas64 { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var myAttachment = new EmailMessage._Attachment
{
    ...
}
```

By the way: there is no real need for a `struct`. Using a `class` would be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `myEmailMessage.Attachment = my Attachment;` is attempting to assign something to a member called `Attachment`. The problem is that you don't have a property called `Attachment` on your class. You have declared a `struct` called that but that is just a declaration and doesn't create a property or anything else like that.

What you'd need is to have an actual property on your class that you could then assign an instance of `Attachment` to.

Answer (score 1):

Your `EmailMessage` class doesn't have an `Attachment` property, only an `Attachment` nested type.

You should rename the `Attachment` struct to `EmailAttachment` to avoid name conflicts, and create an `Attachment` property:

```
public class EmailMessage
{
    public EmailAddress To { get; set; }

    public EmailAddress From { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public EmailAttachment Attachment { get; set; }

    public struct EmailAttachment
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Bas64 { get; set; }
    }
}
```